# What do you call this thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What do you call a meal where people serve themselves or food that is arranged on a table?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean 'buffet'?  Also see this answer for a variety of meal structures: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163233/3-course-menu-al-carte-buffet-etc-what-do-you-call-these-dining-format

Comment: This appears to be almost verbatim the definition of *buffet* given in [this dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=pqlRO2jdI2gC&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false). I found this very quickly by searching Google. Please try to find the answer for yourself first.

Answer (score 4):

This type of meal is commonly referred to as a [*buffet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffet), which is named after the French word for a piece of furniture it can be served on.

> [image]

<sub>image copied from Wikipedia, original author Dorina Andress (Eberswalde)</sub>